# Scala Spark load saved MLlib model

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have saved a Random Forest model in my S3 path and now i want to load it. However, i got an error that method does not exist.

**code (saving model works):**

```
import org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassifier

    val rfClassifier = new RandomForestClassifier()
      .setImpurity("gini")
      .setMaxDepth(8)
      .setNumTrees(200)
      .setFeatureSubsetStrategy("auto")
      .setSeed(18)

   val rfModel = rfClassifier.fit(trainingFeatures)
    rfModel
    .write
    .overwrite()
    .save(<MY S3 PATH>)
```

**Code (loading model doesnt work):**

```
val rfmodel = RandomForestClassifier.load(<MY S3 PATH>)
)
```

**Error:**

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.apache.spark.ml.classification.RandomForestClassificationModel.<init>(java.lang.String)
```

Not sure why this error is occurring when the load method exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should load `RandomForestClassificationModel` not `RandomForestClassifier`.

Replace with:

```scala
val rfmodel = RandomForestClassificationModel.load(<MY S3 PATH>)
```

More about model persistence [here](https://databricks.com/blog/2016/05/31/apache-spark-2-0-preview-machine-learning-model-persistence.html)

Comment: Thanks, just want to show how to import this: `import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.model.RandomForestModel`